# R Copy column with less characters

Tags: r

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
Tree  Species
5     rops_002
6     tico_001
8     tico_004
```

I need to add a column with less characters, like this:

```
Tree  Species   Species1
5     rops_002  rops
6     tico_001  tico
8     tico_004  tico
```

does somebody know how to do this? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dt <- data.frame(a = 1:2)
dt$Species <- c("assa_12", "bssa_12")
dt
#   a Species
# 1 1 assa_12
# 2 2 bssa_12
```

One way:

```
dt$Species1 <- substr(dt$Species, 1, 4)
dt
#   a Species Species1
# 1 1 assa_12     assa
# 2 2 bssa_12     bssa
```

Second option:

```
dt$Species1 <- sapply(strsplit(dt$Species, "_"), function(x) x[1])
dt
#   a Species Species1
# 1 1 assa_12     assa
# 2 2 bssa_12     bssa
```

### More functions and benchmarks:

```
minem1 <- function(x) substr(x, 1, 4) # takes firs 4 characters
minem2 <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "_"), function(x) x[1]) # splits by "_" and takes first part
minem3 <- function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "_", fixed = T), function(x) x[1]) # the same
andrewGustar <- function(x) gsub("_\\d+", "", x) # replaces anything after "_" with ""
koenV <- function(x) sub(x, pattern = "_.+", replacement = "") #changed a little

require(data.table)
setDT(dt)
minem4 <- function(x) data.table::tstrsplit(x, "_", fixed = T)[[1]]
# also splits and takes first part

# creata large test case:
n <- 100000
dt <- data.frame(a = 1:n,
Species = sample(c("aaaa", "abda", "asdf", "dads"), n, replace = T))
dt$Species <- paste(dt$Species, dt$a, sep = "_")


require(microbenchmark)
bench <- microbenchmark(minem1(dt$Species),
                        minem2(dt$Species),
                        andrewGustar(dt$Species),
                        koenV(dt$Species),
                        minem3(dt$Species),
                        minem4(dt$Species))
bench
Unit: milliseconds
# expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq       max neval  cld
# minem1(dt$Species)   5.12257   5.465827   5.655002   5.620615   5.818871   6.94633   100 a   
# minem2(dt$Species) 126.19138 133.780757 167.598675 176.696708 186.330236 627.31002   100    d
# andrewGustar(dt$Species)  40.24816  41.988833  42.591255  42.549435  42.942418  48.48893   100  b  
# koenV(dt$Species)  37.91208  39.528120  40.369007  40.412091  40.885594  46.52658   100  b  
# minem3(dt$Species)  80.40778  86.622198 112.163038  90.496686 137.788859 575.97141   100   c 
# minem4(dt$Species)  15.28590  16.111006  17.737274  16.552911  17.054645  69.07255   100 a 
autoplot(bench)
```

[image]

Conclusions: if you are sure that `Species1` is 4 character long string then use `substr`, if not, then try `tstrsplit` from `data.table`. Also you could look at `stringr` and `stringi` packages for faster character sub-setting.

Comment: Thank you all very much - the "one way" option worked perfect in my case!

Answer (score 1):

Or `df$Species1 <- gsub("_\\d+","",df$Species)`

This will remove the _nnn part, whereas minem's answer just keeps the first four characters.  It depends what you want!  If they are always in the AAAA_nnn format, then both are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

one very simple way may be:

```
df$Species1 <- sub(x = df$Species, pattern = "_00.", replacement = "")
```

if your pattern to remove is always `_00x`, where x is one digit